# Share (push to) git repo without giving write permissions

Tags: git, encryption, version-control, permissions

I'm working on a collaborative project and we've set up a git repo to manage the code. It's on a server I host, shared via ssh (the repo is on /srv/project). The only way I found to share push access to my teammates is creating a new user for each, adding them  to a "project" group, and making the repo directory writable by that group.

This has a disadvantage: if any of my teammates decides to ssh into the server and `rm -rf` the whole repo, I can't do anything about it. It's not that I don't trust  them, but "better safe than sorry" (also big organizations must have a solution for this issue).

Is there a way to grant push capabilities but no write perms?

Using SSH is a MUST. GitHub  is not acceptable either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a dedicated account, say with username `git`, that uses `git-shell` as its shell instead of bash. That is, change the account in `/etc/passwd` from this:

```
git:x:1000:1000::/home/git:/bin/sh
```

to this:

```
git:x:1000:1000::/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

It is also recommended to use ssh keys for authentication instead of passwords. I took this example from the Pro Git book, where it's explained in more detail:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

If you don't have permissions to modify user accounts (for example on a shared hosting), you can use ssh keys with a command restriction in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, like this:

```
command="perl -e 'exec qw(git-shell -c), $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}'",no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB...
```

This way authorized users can login with ssh, but instead of a regular shell, they will be restricted to `git-shell`. This is a bit hackish, it's better if you can just change the shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Great. I can even create two users for each person, "john" and "john-git" so they can push to the repo as john-git, but can't write to it as "john". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/master-toc.html). Gitolite is an access control layer that lets you serve git repositories over ssh without granting general shell access, and provides you with features like restricting who can push to certain branches, as well.

If you want something more graphical but self-hosted, [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) is quite nice.